# Sort RxList from getX dart package for Flutter app

Tags: list, sorting, flutter, observable

I'm not able to sort an observable RxList by a given attribute. Sorting was working fine when I was using BloC approach, using a simple List.

Recently I changed the State Management to GetX (https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) package, as I saw several advantages (no need of contexts, transitions to pages, etc).

There are two scenarios here, my bad, did not explain it earlier, let me put in gherkin's

**Scenario 1**:

```
Given user in Posts Screen
When user Pull down to get Newest posts
Then user get the newly fetched posts on top of the previous loaded list
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
Given user in Posts Screen
When user reaches the end of the list
Then user get more posts at the end of the previous loaded list
```

**post_model.dart**

```
class Post {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final DateTime date;
  final User user;

Post({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.date,
    this.user});
 
}
```

**post_controller.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';
import 'package:blog/models/post.dart';
import 'package:blog/services/posts_api.dart';

class PostsController extends GetxController {
  int _page = 0;

  ---------HERE OBS LIST-----------
  RxList posts = [].obs;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    this.loadPosts();
  }

  Future<void> loadPosts({isRefreshLoad = false}) async {
    int pager;
    if (isRefreshLoad) {
      pager = 1;
    } else {
      increment();
      pager = this._page;
    }

    Map<String, String> arguments = {'page': '$pager'};
    final List<Post> newPosts =
        await PostsApi.instance.getPosts(arguments: arguments);

    // remove duplicates
    posts.addAll(
      newPosts.where(
        (newPosts) => posts.every((post) => newPosts.id != post.id),
      ),
    );

    //----------HERE'S THE EXCEPTION----------
    posts.sort((a, b) => b.id.compareTo(a.id));
    update(['posts']);
  }
}
```

error

```
flutter: [GETX] PostsController has been initialized
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Post' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
#0      RxList.remove 
package:get/…/rx/rx_impl.dart:333
```

**PostsScreen.dart**

```
Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
                appBar: AppBarWidget(
                  drawerOpen: drawerPosition,
                  appBarVisible: _isVisible,
                  drawerVisible: true,
                ),
                body: ColorfulSafeArea(
                  overflowRules: OverflowRules.only(left: true, bottom: true),
                  child: GetBuilder<PostsController>(
                    id: 'posts',
                    init: PostsController(),
                    builder: (_postsController) {
                      _postsControllerGlobal = _postsController;
                      // Scenario 1 - Triggers when user pull down to get new posts
                      return RefreshIndicator( 
                        onRefresh: () {
                          return _postsController.loadPosts(
                              isRefreshLoad: true);
                        },
                        child: StreamBuilderWidget(
                          stream: _postsController.posts.stream,
                         // Scenario 2 Triggers when scroll controller reaches end of list
                          scrollController: _scrollController,                               isDrawerOpen: _isDrawerOpen,
                          widgetType: 'PostItemWidget',
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

----`enter code here`------

I need a way to always re-order the list of fetched Posts in date desc order after they been added to the stream, whether the trigger has been PullDown or reached the final end of the list, in order the always display items in Published order.

Hope someone can give me a hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after days trying to figure it out I found out it was much simpler and due to my lack of knowledge.

As the list is an observable just converting it into a list was enough to accomplish the sort:

Normal List

- newPosts.sort((a, b) => b.date.compareTo(a.date));

Observable List

- newPosts.toList().sort((a, b) => b.date.compareTo(a.date));

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First order your list and then you add it

```
final List<Post> newPosts =
        await PostsApi.instance.getPosts(arguments: arguments);

//----------Try this---------
newPosts.sort((a, b) => b.id.compareTo(a.id));
    
// remove duplicates
    posts.addAll(
      newPosts.where(
        (newPosts) => posts.every((post) => newPosts.id != post.id),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, added more information to original post. You answer won't cover the to scenarios (once again apologise should have added them earlier).

Scenario 1, with your replay will add them to end of the list. My aim is to add them on top of the list as I'm fetching newly added posts to the list, and not previous posts.

Thanks again